# Drop down opitions on Calendar Overlay View

Tags: list-view, calendar, sharepoint-calendar, overlay

Morning

I have a Calendar which I set up some different views. What I want to do is if a user picks say IT Service Management they only add an event for that calendar and if they choose Out of Hours - Infrastructure they only add to that calendar. I've done it before but for the life of me can't remember how...

[image]

Comment: Your second sentence is confusing. What does "that calendar" mean? A calendar in SharePoint is nothing else than a list view of a list that is using the Event content type. Are you talking about different list views, each of a calendar type where you display different events based on the values of the fields of each event?

Comment: Yes that's what I mean, so for example if the user selects IT Service they have the choice of adding an item which is a) b) c) or d).

Comment: So thinking this out I need a Radio Button of Four choices which each give a different drop down option.

Comment: In that case you need to modify your calendar list views (or create them if they don't already exist) and set some filters based on values of a field(s).

Comment: So I could add a filter which when a user clicks to add an item which would show a different drop down choice depending on their choice?

Comment: You mean that when you click add item from inside the calendar, the form should open up having one or more fields already filled in with some specific value?

Comment: No. When a user clicks add a new item one of the choices they've got is a drop down or radio button saying:
IT Service Management
Our of Hours - Lap Top
Out of Hours - Desktop

depending on what they choose it then gives them a further set of choices so if they pick Out of Hours Lap Top, they get
Mr A
Mr B and if they pick Desktop they get:
Mr C
Mr D

Comment: Ah, I see what you want now. I suggest that you update your question to say exactly that because currently nobody could guess that you want a cascading of drop-down fields. Also, say which version of SharePoint you are working with and if you want a JavaScript solution or InfoPath solution. Before someone provides you with an answer, search the Inernet for "sharepoint cascading drop-down" and you will find lots of examples.